# Configure coverage.py to use no migrations

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, coverage.py, test-coverage

I am using [Django Test Without Migrations](https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-test-without-migrations) to make my unit tests faster and I run the tests the following way:

```
python manage.py test --nomigrations
```

It significantly improved the speed.

I want to do the same with PyCharm and coverage.py in order to take advantage of visuals PyCharm creates.

I tried to add this to .coveragerc:

```
[run]

omit =
    */migrations/*
```

But it turns out that it affects only reports.

How can I do this?

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this without migrations?

Comment: @MhFarahani unfortunately, no. Currently doing it from the command line. please let me know if you manage to configure it

Comment: I think I figure it out! go to `Run/Debug Configurations` in pyCharm. Then on left hand side select `Python` (not Django tests!). Script will be the path to `manage.py`, script parameters will be from test to the end of your command line. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have professional version with django support:
[image]

Click on `Edit configurations`

[image]

Choose Django tests from defaults and add --nomigrations to options input.

If you don't have django support in Pycharm it not that different

Also make sure to use correct python interpreter and refer to [awesome doc page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-django-test.html).

Comment: Make sure to use correct python interpreter. Also refer to awesome doc page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-django-test.html. I'll add it to answer

Comment: I have the options ticked and chose the correct Python interpreter. I have `test_without_migrations` defined first in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Still I get the following error: `django_test_manage.py test: error: unrecognized arguments: --nomigrations`

Comment: @physicalattraction Does it work from terminal? What is `django_test_manage.py` script?

Comment: Yes, it is working from the terminal. I have no clue what the `django_test_manage.py` script is, probably something internal from PyCharm.