# Configure a django test with no migrations in pyCharm

Tags: django, python-2.7, unit-testing, pycharm

I am new to both django and pycharm! I can run the tests in my code on terminal using:

```
python manage.py test Repo/tests/testUnit1.py --failfast -n
```

and it works! Recently, I tried to use pycharm (professional) to run and debug the tests. The problem is that when I specify the option `--nomigrations` it gives the following error:

```
Usage: /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py test [options] 

[path.to.modulename|path.to.modulename.TestCase|path.to.modulename.TestCase.test_method]...

Discover and run tests in the specified modules or the current directory.

/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py: error: no such option: --nomigrations
```

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888628/configure-coverage-py-to-use-no-migrations) but it suggests the same thing that I have already tried. Does this happen because the test unit and the code that I want to test are not in the same folder? How can I run a test in pycharm without migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. I edited `Python Run/Debug configuration` and passed `manage.py` to `Script`. Also, I pasted the path that I used to use on command terminal (plus --failfast -n at the end) in `Script parameters` and it starts working!

Answer (score 4):

In case this saves someone else some time here is how to set it up (took me awhile to figure out the first couple steps)...

- Select *Edit configurations*
- Create a new *Python* configuration (not a *Django tests* configuration)
- In *Script* put `manage.py`
- In *Script parameters* put `test --nomigrations <optional test labels>`
- Optionally may need to specify a *Working directory*, depending on how PyCharm is started
- As always, make sure your *Environment variables*, *Python interpreter* and *Interpreter options* are set to your project

This is on PyCharm 2016.2.3 and Django 1.8.9 with [django-test-without-migrations](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-test-without-migrations/) installed

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use the configuration menu, I just edit the source.

You'll see when running tests that PyCharm that it uses its work test runner, something like

```
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py
```

Opening it up, I add the [functional part that's taken from django-test-without-migrations](https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-test-without-migrations/blob/master/test_without_migrations/management/commands/test.py#L17)

```
# added this class
class DisableMigrations(object):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return "notmigrations"


# ... right before this built-in
class PycharmTestCommand(Command):
  def get_runner(self):
    TEST_RUNNER = 'django_test_runner.run_tests'
    test_path = TEST_RUNNER.split('.')
    #....
```

Then, inside of the `PycharmTestCommand.handle()` method:

```
def handle(self, *test_labels, **options):
    # Add this line
    settings.MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
    # That's it!
    # ....
```

Now it works on all your projects, whether or not they have that lib installed. I still install the lib in case I need to run tests outside of PyCharm.

Comment: Update for Django 1.9+:  `DisableMigrations.__getitem__` can/should return `None` rather than a fake module name.